# SQLite database not loading on iphone device

Tags: iphone, xcode, sqlite, ios-simulator

When I test my app on the simulator everything works. But when I test the app on my iPhone, it doesn't load from the db.sqlite3 data base.

I tried every solution from the internet. I cleaned the app. I added the database to the build phrases - copy bundle resources etc.
Can you help me? Is there any fails in my coding?

```
-(void)openDataBase{

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    dbPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"db.sqlite3"];

    //load it
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *pathInRessource = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"db" ofType:@"sqlite3"];

    //exist it?
    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath]) {
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:pathInRessource toPath:dbPath error:nil];
    }

    //open database
    int result = sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db);
    if (result != SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_close(db);

        return;
    }

    //if ok
    NSLog(@"Data base opened");

}
```

Comment: Well, you have a bunch of code there.  When you step through it, when do you notice something going awry?  And what error messages are you ignoring?

Comment: Hey on the simulator i got the message "Data base opened" but when i run it on the iphone i get no message. I think, the iphone can't find the path. But i don't know how to solve it.

Comment: I'd specifically look at what `sqlite3_open()` returned and check that against http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html

Comment: My guess is you get the wrong path (that would explain why it works in the simulator, where it is different), it should look like `file:///var/mobile/Applications/...id.../Documents/YourDatabase.sqlite`. Try copying the code to find a path from another source.

Comment: I looked at it. Its showing db = NULL. And db is sqlite3 *db; But my data base (db) isn't empty. On the simulator it works.

Comment: Ok i will try with that path

Comment: Also `copyItemAtPath` returns a `BOOL` that you should probably be looking at

Comment: i tried with other paths..not loading :( i will try delete and run new

Comment: that's what copyItemPath returns: /var/mobile/Applications/..id../test.app/db.sqlite3

Comment: [According to the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsfilemanager_class/reference/reference.html#jumpTo_14) it returns a `BOOL`, not a string. You should probably also not be swallowing the error like you are using `nil`

Comment: -1 for ignoring errors.

Answer (score 2):

At the time of opening database you can call this with its else case to get the issue.

```
if (sqlite3_open([getDBPath UTF8String], &sqlhandle) == SQLITE_OK)
{
     NSLog(@"Database Open!");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Select err: %s",sqlite3_errmsg(sqlhandle));
}
```

You will be able to get proper error message using this

Comment: Now i debugged with the iOS simulator and with my device. Then I compared the results. The only different is my integer result. On simulator result = 0. On device = 4. On iOS simulator its going from the if statement to the NSLog. On device its going from if to close and return. I don't understand that at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I am wondring where you getting stuck, I am doing same way and its working fine to me.

BTW I have updated your code, how I am handling, please check let me know if find and trouble in this.

```
//My DB variable
static sqlite3 *database;

-(void)openDataBase{
if (database == NULL) 

    sqlite3 *mDatabse;

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    dbPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"db.sqlite3"];

    //load it
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *pathInRessource = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"db" ofType:@"sqlite3"];

    //exist it?
    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath]) {
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:pathInRessource toPath:dbPath error:nil];
    }

    if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &mDatabse) == SQLITE_OK) {   
            NSLog(@"Database Successfully Opened");
            database = mDatabse;


        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error in opening database");
            mDatabse = NULL;
        }

}
```

Comment: When you say "My Class variable", do you actually mean an instance variable?

Comment: yeah either you can declare it in header or implementation file. sorry if it confusing you, i just updated

Comment: Well, I wasn't confused, but whether a class- or instance-variable is used will have an impact on the number of instances of this class that can be used simultaneously.  You appear to have made the worse choice.

Comment: I agree about the impact of class and instance variable, but I use this variable to check database then I have one local variable with that I do database operation, still If you find It can be improved, I would welcome.

Comment: That's very easy; make it an instance variable in a private category of the class: `@implementation Database () { sqlite3 *_database; } ... @implementation Database { ... }`.  This allows multiple instances of this class to exist, which could prove very useful.

Comment: Sure I'll do the changes, but How about your problem, are you able to resolve that?

Comment: I am not the OP, so you'll have to refer to him/her.

Comment: Hi RDC thanks for your answer. I tried it on your way. Unfortunately same problem. On the simulator everything fine, on my iPhone not showing anything from the database. I thing there is some problem in my settings. I will check now step by step.

Comment: Now i debugged with the iOS simulator and with my device. Then I compared the results. The only different is my integer result. On simulator result = 0. On device = 4. On iOS simulator its going from the if statement to the NSLog. On device its going from if to close and return. I don't understand that at the moment.